# Several Configurable Drop Down Lists

Tags: javascript, list, drop-down-menu

I was searching for a drop down list script that auto-updates the content below the drop-down list in several sub-drop down lists derived from the choice made in the initial drop-down list selection.

I tried out the script at http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/dynamic-drop-down-list.html and spent 6 hours trying to make it work in my favour, but I have come to the conclusion that I am definitely doing something wrong and would need help.

I would like to start off with a drop-down list that contains "Classes" of a computer that can be built. For instance; Ultimate, High, Mid, Low. When a user selects one of those options, the below drop-down unlocks, giving new options, and when that option is chosen the below updates, etc, etc till the last item which is the end of the form.

It is a project to allow a user to build a PC for themselves, but owing to the fact that a motherboard has certain limitations such as RAM amount or CPU allowance the drop-down that houses RAM/CPU would have to adapt to the motherboard chosen, etc.

A basic layout I have in mind is;

**Please choose a Class**

[Dropdown 1 "Class"]

- Ultimate
- High
- Medium
- Low

[Dropdown 2 "Motherboard"]

- Content

[Dropdown 3 "RAM"]

- Content

[Dropdown 4 "CPU"]

- Content

[Dropdown 5 "Optical Drives"]

- Content

[Dropdown 6 "Hard Drives"]

- Content

[Dropdown 7 "Chassis"]

- Content

[Dropdown 8 "Power Supply"]

- Content

Etc. So when lets say you have a motherboard that only support 8GB of RAM, then the RAM sub-dropdown would show options 2GB, 4GB and 8GB, but not additional options such as 16GB or 32GB. The drop-down shouldn't be locked to just 1 drop-down, but be flexible throughout in case motherboard/cpu/ram incompatibilities and hence some items need to be locked out.

Perhaps make a list of items that can be made under category "Ultimate" and make my way down to "Low"?

If anyone could assist me with this, I would greatly appreciate it, even point me in a direction of a similar project of which the above has been accomplished.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another

Comment: The term you're searching for is "Cascading Dropdowns." Do a Google search for it; you'll find boatloads of information on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have checked them out, but most support only a limited amount, and some without even the basic documentation. The one provided by Sean Johnson/sachleen is heavily documented and even comes with a config file making it even more easier. I've studied the config a bit, and seems quite straightforward so I'll see what I can do. Thanks to everyone for the assist thus far, and I'll try my best from here on out! If I get stuck hopefully one of you would kindly help me out. :) I'll be sure to update the outcome whichever way this goes.

Comment: I have managed to make the script work for me, however I would like to add an option where when the user selects an item a total at the bottom of the page will be updated, for each product, so the final choices are shown with the total and used in a form to send me the information. I found http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/auto-sum-checkboxes.html however I have no idea how to implement it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

[Chained Select Menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chainedmenu/index.htm)

Comment: How about providing some context, a brief summary of what is at the link?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Thanks for the informative post, I'll keep that in mind in the future! :)