# show hide the selected option trigger 2nd select option then 2nd select option trigger hide show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Here are my code:

```
<p><label for="category"><b>Services / Package</b></label>
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="GC">General</option>
<option value="RFU">Routine</option>
<option value="HPS">Health</option>
<option value="CRP">Corporate</option>
</select></p>
<!--Level 2 hide-->
<p id="gc" style="display: none;">
<label for="GC"><b>Select Doctor</b></label>
<select name="GC" id="GC">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="scheduleA">Dr A</option>
<option value="scheduleB">Dr B</option>
</select></p>
<p id="rfu" style="display: none;">
<label for="RFU"><b>Select Doctor</b></label>
<select name="RFU" id="RFU">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="scheduleA">Dr A</option>
<option value="scheduleC">Dr C</option>
</select></p>
<p id="hsp" style="display: none;">
<label for="HPS"><b>Select Package</b></label>
<select name="HPS" id="HPS">
<option value=" ">-- select --</option>
<option value="msg">Package D</option>
<option value="msg">Package E</option>
</select></p>
<!--Level 3 Show hide-->
<p id="CRP" style="display: none;">Please state at remark</p>
<p id="scheduleA" style="display: none;">Table schedule A</p>
<p id="scheduleB" style="display: none;">Table schedule B</p>
<p id="scheduleC" style="display: none;">Table schedule C</p>
<p id="msg" style="display: none;">Please go to this website</p>
```

Can somebody help me to create jquery or javascript on this coding.

I've tried using http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/ and have to combine with other jquery seems the result not solving the problem

I've make http://jsfiddle.net/6rTa5/ 
problem here:
- choose from 1st select option
- choose from 2nd select option
- div show
- directly choose again at 1st select option
- the div are stuck there it is not hiding, unless i go previous option to select null then it gone

Comment: I dont understand ur problem

Comment: where is div in  http://jsfiddle.net/6rTa5/

Comment: @Laughing I can't put div in the fiddle due it use other jquery different from the dropdown box jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show the second dropdown box while choosing a option from
1st dropdown listbox?
 And by changing the 1st dropdown's option, the 2nd dropdown selected option's to be unselect or reset?

Not sure. Please be clear.

Comment: after choosing 1st dropdown box it will show 2nd dropdown box, then choose from 2nd dropdown box will show div, but the stories is when you leave the one you choose at 2nd dropdown box, and directly choose again at 1st dropdown box, the div are stuck there it won't hide.

Comment: You should reset the 2nd dropdown box value, while onchange the 1st dropdown, so the div will get hide.

Comment: how to reset it, I use change function for both dropdown box, for the moment I've to select null (2nd dropdown box) for the div to hide. Is there any where to reset it without select null option?

Comment: Try, document.getElementById("2nd dropdown id").selectedIndex = -1;

Comment: I've found the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)