# multiple select option value validating in php

Tags: php

I have multiple select option value for online appointment form. My project is just like this project 
[(Show a second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)

I've on some jquery code to clear the option when user choose other option, the things is how I am going to validate the form, what I mean is at least one select option are selected at second level select option value.

I've tried using this code at validation php page

```
else if ($appointment_gc == " " 
         || $appointment_fu == " " 
         || $appointment_gas == " " 
         || $appointment_col == " " 
         || $appointment_ent == " " 
         || $appointment_ort == " " 
         || $appointment_ps == " " 
         || $appointment_package == " " ) {
            echo "Submission fails. You have not choose any package. 
                  Please go back and try again.
                  <input style=\"padding:10px 20px;margin-top:20px;\" 
                  type=button value=\"Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1)\">"; 
          exit();
}
```

each of `$appointment_...` are select option.
I just want that at least one select option are selected, but seems that no matter how all failed to submit.

Comment: what are you getting in $appointment_gc??

Comment: Why is every option stored in a dedicated variable? You are using "or" instead of "and", what would be the better choice, I guess ^^ If all fields are empty (empty AND empty AND ...), submission fails

Comment: @Hasina - in $appointment_gc I'll get doctor's name in it.

Comment: @strauberry - I can't use "and" because not all the select option are selected, only one select option will be choose

Comment: @AhBui yes that's true! You want to say "if no option was selected, then fail" so all options must be empty.... and hence, AND is the right selection

Comment: @AhBui - I think you should show complete code to make us to answer.

Comment: @strauberry - sorry for late reply, I've just use ur recommendation using '&&' it works, thanks guys