# Displaying second dropdown menu based on first dropdown menu options NOT working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have done extensive research on how to display a second dropdown box based on the selection of the primary.  stackoverflow has been awesome and they appear to work in jsfiddle for each case.  Unfortunately, when I apply them to my code they are not functional.  I am giving you an example of what I found and my code applying this code.  Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you sooooo much.

[stackoverflow problem fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>OutInMaine</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('maps/maine3.gif');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
footer 
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:120px; /* choose any height */
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#regions').bind('change', function () {
    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
}).trigger('change'); // Setup the initial states
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function transfer() {
var url = "http://"+window.opener.location.hostname+window.opener.location.pathname;
var queryString;
var x = document.getElementById('regions');
queryString = '?regions='+x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
window.opener.location.replace(url+queryString);
window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="moveTo(200,200); resizeTo(600,850);">
<footer>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<br/><p align="right">Region to display: 
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    <option value="Aroostock">Aroostock</option>
    <option value="DownEast/Acadia">DownEast/Acadia</option>
    <option value="Highlands">Highlands</option>
    <option value="Kennebec/Moose River">Kennebec/Moose River</option>
    <option value="Lakes/Mountains">Lakes/Mountains</option>
    <option value="Mid-coast">Mid-Coast</option>
    <option value="Southern">Southern</option>
    <option value="SpecificCity">Specific City</option>
    <option value="Maine" selected="selected">Maine</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" onclick="transfer()"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="SpecificCity" id="SpecificCity" style="display:none">
<select name="cities" id="cities">
    <option value="calais">Calais</option>
    <option value="bangor">Bangor</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understand from your code you are trying to filter second dropdown options according to selection upon first one, but you forgot to give classes to options from second dropdown, that corresponds with values from first one, thats why your `show` method couldn't find anything

add classes to options :

```
 <option value="calais" class="Mid-coast">Calais</option>
```

and modify a little your code :

```
$('#regions').bind('change', function () {
    var elements = $('div.container').find("option").hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length && $('div.container').find('.' + value).length) { // if somethings' selected
        $('div.container').show();
        $('div.container').find('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }else{
        $('div.container').hide();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8rGrb/5/)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and do not have any change in results.  The second dropdown does not appear.  I double checked for typos and nothing.  I also looked at your DEMO and could not get that to work as well.  According to your coding, the second dropdown should appear if Mid-coast is selected on the primary.  Is that correct?  I want it to be ONLY "Specific City" but I can make those changes after it is functional.