# Show second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to html/javascript and I am developing and trying to figure out how to use the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection).

I can see the solution presented in below link, but not sure how to apply in the context of the html page:
http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/3/

I have copied the HTML and JavaScript function content within a HTML page, but it basically displays all the lines and select boxes... any idea how is this intended to work? Should I have a separate html page with the html code and the JavaScript function in a different file and somehow call the 2 together?

```
<select size="1" id="Rank" title="" name="Rank">
    <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="airman">Airman</option>
    <option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="airman">
        <select class="second-level-select">
            <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-1">Basic Ore Miner - Level 1</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-2">Basic Ore Miner - Level 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="senior-airman">
        <select class="second-level-select">
            <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-1">Omber Miner - Level 1</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-2">Omber Miner - Level 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="second-level-container">
    <div class="basic-ore-1">
        Line of text for basic ore miner 1
    </div>
    <div class="basic-ore-2">
        Line of text for basic ore miner 2
    </div>
    <div class="omber-miner-1">
        Line of text for omber miner 1
    </div>
    <div class="omber-miner-2">
        Line of text for omber miner 2
    </div>    
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Rank').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');

    $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should include you script into  and page will be like:

```
<html >
<head >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Rank').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
}).trigger('change');

$('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
}).trigger('change');
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <select size="1" id="Rank" title="" name="Rank">
        <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
        <option value="airman">Airman</option>
        <option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
    </select>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="airman">
            <select class="second-level-select">
                <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
                <option value="basic-ore-1">Basic Ore Miner - Level 1</option>
                <option value="basic-ore-2">Basic Ore Miner - Level 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="senior-airman">
            <select class="second-level-select">
                <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
                <option value="omber-miner-1">Omber Miner - Level 1</option>
                <option value="omber-miner-2">Omber Miner - Level 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="second-level-container">
        <div class="basic-ore-1">
            Line of text for basic ore miner 1
        </div>
        <div class="basic-ore-2">
            Line of text for basic ore miner 2
        </div>
        <div class="omber-miner-1">
            Line of text for omber miner 1
        </div>
        <div class="omber-miner-2">
            Line of text for omber miner 2
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI... I have tried the above and copied your code into a html page, but does not seem to work... I still see all the lines and the filtering not working :(

Comment: HI... looks like the below link seems to work:
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"

Comment: @user3652574 that`s i mean

Comment: @user3652574 if you problem solved you should close question by accepting answer