# Show second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorry to bring this up despite there beeing many post regarding this subject, like:
[Show a second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)

Though and after trying loads of stuff stated on those posts, I can't make it work.

ISSUE-The problem is the 3 Select boxes #time, #rental and #place won't show/hide once there's a selection on Select Box #course.

Below the simple code and the related fiddle.

Thanks once again for all your support, regards
Cheers
MSV

https://jsfiddle.net/marcosv/retf6kwu/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#course").change(function() {
            $("#fishingoptions").hide();
            } if ($(this).val() === "Phase 1") {
                $("#time").hide();
                $("#rental").hide();
                $("#place").hide();
            }
            else if ($(this).val() === "Phase 2") {
                $("#time").hide();
                $("#rental").show();
                $("#place").show();
            } 
            else if ($(this).val() === "Phase 3") {
                $("#time").hide();
                $("#rental").show();
                $("#place").show();
            }
            else if ($(this).val() === "Guiding") {
                $("#time").show();
                $("#rental").show();
                $("#place").show();
            } 
            else {
                $('#time').show();
                $('#rental').show();
                $('#place').show();
            }
        });.trigger('change');
    });
</script>

<p>
        Select Course <select Name="Course" width="100%" required id="course">
        <option value="empty">-</option>
        <option value="Guiding">Guiding</option>
        <option value="Phase1">Phase 1</option>
        <option value="Phase2">Phase 2</option>
        <option value="Phase3">Phase 3</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <div id="fishingoptions">
        <div id="time">
        <p>
        Fishing time? <select Name="Fishing Time" width="100%" required>
        <option value="empty">-</option>
        <option value="1day">Full day</option>
        <option value="1/2day">1/2 day</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id="rental">
        <p>
        Equipment rental? <select Name="Equipment Rental" width="100%" required>
        <option value="empty">-</option>
        <option value="no">no</option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id="place">
        <p>
        Where do you want to fish? <select Name="Where to fish" width="100%" required>
        <option value="empty">-</option>
        <option value="Odeleite River" style="color:green">Odeleite River</option>
        <option value="Guadiana River" style="color:green">Guadiana River</option>
        <option value="Vascão River" style="color:green">Vascão River</option>
        <option value="Odeceixe River" style="color:green">Odeceixe River</option>
        <option value="Aljezur River" style="color:green">Aljezur River</option>
        <option value="Alvor River" style="color:green">Alvor River</option>
        <option value="Arade River" style="color:green">Arade River</option>
        <option value="Odeleite Dam" style="color:blue">Odeleite Dam</option>
        <option value="Beliche Dam" style="color:blue">Beliche Dam</option>
        <option value="Odelouca Dam" style="color:blue">Odelouca Dam</option>
        <option value="Funcho/Arade Dam" style="color:blue">Funcho/Arade Dam</option>
        <option value="Bravura Dam" style="color:blue">Bravura Dam</option>
        <option value="Santa Clara Dam" style="color:blue">Santa Clara Dam</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is, and what's not working.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your reply. If you check the fiddle you will see that hide/show behaviours are not working. Just added a text line on the question, check "ISSUE". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you actually need and there are some errors in your code.

For example that `.trigger('change');` at the end of your jQuery shouldn't be there.

You are targeting values with `Phase 1` while in HTML they are set like `Phase1`

I changed your code a bit and with this you could get what you need:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#course select").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "Phase1") {
          $("#time").hide();
          $("#rental").hide();
          $("#place").hide();
        } else if ($(this).val() === "Phase2") {
        console.log($(this).val());
          $("#time").hide();
          $("#rental").show();
          $("#place").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() === "Phase3") {
          $("#time").hide();
          $("#rental").show();
          $("#place").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() === "Guiding") {
          $("#time").show();
          $("#rental").show();
          $("#place").show();
        } else {
          $('#time').show();
          $('#rental').show();
          $('#place').show();
        }
      });
    });
```

Full example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/retf6kwu/2/

Comment: Thanks jakob. I dont understand though ince i had in HTML value="Phase 1" with a space... Anyway, it works now, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code.

```
$("#course").change(function() {
            $("#fishingoptions").hide();
            } if ($(this).val() === "Phase 1") {
//          ^ closes the change function prematurely.

});.trigger('change');
//^ this breaks everything.


$('#time').show();
```

The elements have these classes, not ids.

```
else if ($(this).val() === "Phase 3") {
```

This doesn't refer to anything meaningful and uses the wrong value. You want:

```
else if ($(this).prop( 'value ) === "Phase3") {
```

`$("#fishingoptions").hide();` hides the containing element which will hide all of the elements it contains.

Here's a Codepen: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/xOxYwa

The fixed Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#course").change(function() {
    $("#fishingoptions").hide();
    if ($(this).prop( 'value' ) === "Phase1") {
      $(".time").hide();
      $(".rental").hide();
      $(".place").hide();
      console.log( "value: " + $( this ).prop( 'value' ));
    } else if ($(this).prop( 'value' ) === "Phase2") {
      $(".time").hide();
      $(".rental").show();
      $(".place").show();
      console.log( "value: " + $( this ).prop( 'value' ));
    } else if ($(this).prop( 'value' ) === "Phase3") {
      $(".time").hide();
      $(".rental").show();
      $(".place").show();
      console.log( "value: " + $( this ).prop( 'value' ));
    } else if ($(this).prop('value') === "Guiding") {
      $(".time").show();
      $(".rental").show();
      $(".place").show();
      console.log( "value: " + $( this ).prop( 'value' ));
    } else {
      $('.time').show();
      $('.rental').show();
      $('.place').show();
    }
    $( '#fishingoptions' ).show();
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply but your code didn't work. Cheers