# Show second dropdown menu on change of first selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown that will show a second when the first is selected.

```
<div id="prob_type_1" name="prob_type_1">
<label>Select Problem Type</label>
<select class="form-control required" type="select" title="" id="prob_type_1" name ="prob_type_1">
<?php if ($client_db_number < 15000) { ?>
<option value = "">-Please Select-</option>
<option value = "SS-20 Appliance">SS-20 Appliance</option>
<option value = "BBoxx Appliance">BBoxx Appliance</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="SS-20 Appliance" class="warren" style="display: none;"  onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<label>Select Appliance</label>
<select id="SS-20 Appliance" name ="prob_type_2">
<option value = "Lights">Lights</option>
<option value = "Television">Television</option>
</select>
</div>


<div id="BBoxx Appliance" class="warren" style="display: none;" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<label>Select Appliance</label>
<select id="BBoxx Appliance" name ="prob_type_2">
<option value = "Lights">Lights</option>
<option value = "Television">Television</option>
<option value = "BBoxx Radio">BBoxx Radio</option>
<option value = "Bboxx USB Multi Charger">Bboxx USB Multi Charger</option>
</select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
    $("#prob_type_1").change(function(){
   correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val()
   $(".warren").hide();
   $("#" + correspondingID).show();
    })
</script>
```

the second menu just isn't showing when either of these is selected...

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wazzahenry/6af6jd83/

based on this :http://jsfiddle.net/dKMzk/
and from this question: [Show a second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954556/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)

Comment: you can't use spaces in IDs or Class names

Comment: I'll never get those 2 hours of my life back :/

Comment: Ha. 2 of many to come i'm afraid. :)

Comment: @wazzahenry, you can see my working snippet below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a `style: none` for your multiple select. To solve this, instead of using `$("#" + correspondingID).show();`, I will rather change the style of the element.
- You are declaring your id with an espace character. It is as if you are declaring differents ids for the same element. To solve this, I removed the space character in the ids .

```js
$("#prob_type_1").change(function(){
   var correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val()
   $(".warren").hide();
   correspondingID = correspondingID.replace(" ", "")
   $("#" + correspondingID).css("display", "inherit");
    })
```

```html
<div id="prob_type_1" name="prob_type_1">
<label>Select Problem Type</label>
<select class="form-control required" type="select" title="" id="prob_type_1" name ="prob_type_1">
<?php if ($client_db_number < 15000) { ?>
<option value = "">-Please Select-</option>
<option value = "SS-20 Appliance">SS-20 Appliance</option>
<option value = "BBoxx Appliance">BBoxx Appliance</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="SS-20Appliance" class="warren" style="display: none;"  onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<label>Select Appliance</label>
<select id="SS-20 Appliance" name ="prob_type_2">
<option value = "Lights">Lights</option>
<option value = "Television">Television</option>
</select>
</div>


<div id="BBoxxAppliance" class="warren" style="display: none;" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<label>Select Appliance</label>
<select id="BBoxx Appliance" name ="prob_type_2">
<option value = "Lights">Lights</option>
<option value = "Television">Television</option>
<option value = "BBoxx Radio">BBoxx Radio</option>
<option value = "Bboxx USB Multi Charger">Bboxx USB Multi Charger</option>
</select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```